# How do you write Urs Hölzle in LaTeX and in BibTeX?

Tags: letters

I don't know how to use Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

Or, more simply, (all modern editors can handle utf8):

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
…
\begin{document}
…
Urs Hölzle is a computer scientist.
…
```

Same typing for the `.bib` file if you use `biblatex+biber`

```
author={Urs Hölzle}
```

Answer (score 1):

In BiBTeX:

```
author = {H{\"o}lzle, Urs}
```

This will enable BiBTeX to do proper name sorting.

In LaTeX:

```
Urs H\"olzle is a computer scientist.
```

In a LaTeX document both `H\"{o}lzle` and `H\"olzle` are completely equivalent.  Do not use the BibTeX specific `H{\"o}lzle` in the document (it may display right but it isn't very proper LaTeX).

Comment: No, in BibTeX it should be `H{\"o}lzle`

Comment: This is not expected answer, OP expect solution with unicode.

Comment: What's the difference between H\"{o}lzle, H{\"o}lzle and H\"olzle?  I'm going to take a guess: In BiBTeX one should use {\"o} so that bibtex knows it is a single char that shouldn't be changed.  In LaTeX all three are the same (they look the same in my test, at least) but H\"olzle has the benefit of being less typing.  Am I close?

Comment: In a LaTeX document, typing `H\"{o}lzle` or `H\"olzle` is completely equivalent. Avoid the BibTeX specific `H{\"o}lzle` in the document; in the `.bib` file it should be like this or you may have problems with name sorting.